# Conditionally include child nodes with RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, one-to-many, restful-architecture, rabl

I think I have a very basic case when I'm using rabl to return JSON for standard RESTful controller methods...

First let's say I have a typical one to many relationship with parent and child (let's say customer and accounts):

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
end
```

In my controller for customer I have index and edit - index where I just want to return all Customers (WITHOUT accounts) and edit where I want to return a specific Customer with all of their Accounts.  With index I don't want to return the accounts for obvious performance (N+1) reasons.

In my rabl, I have the following:

```
#index.rabl (for listing all customers)
collection :@customers
extends "customers/_customer"
```

and

```
#edit.rabl (for editing a single customer)
object :@customer
extends "customer/_customer"
```

I am reusing the _customer.rabl for both the index and the edit.

```
#_customer.rabl
object :@customer
attributes :name, ......

if @include_accounts
  child :accounts do
    extends "accounts/_account"
  end
end
```

I set the @include_accounts in my edit (controller) and not the index - but this doesn't work - essentially the instance var here (@include_accounts) never gets passed down.  What is the correct pattern to implement this?

Comment: Which version of the gem are you using, `rabl` or `rabl-rails`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the rails-rabl gem claims it is faster, I found that templates aren't as flexible for conditional expressions  - see rabl-rails readme re: instance variables.

Comment: Thank you.  I switched to the rabl gem and everything worked like a charm.